# Indesign — Object Style - Force Specific Frame Width

Tags: adobe-indesign

Using Indesign CS6.

I'm trying to set up an object style for images so that the frame is always a specific width, and the contents scale proportionally.

Under **Text Frame Auto Size Options**, I've set **Width Only** to **5in** minimum, but it doesn't seem to apply.

Additionally, in **General Options**, I've set **Columns** to **Fixed Width**, **1 column**, **Width** **5in**; also doesn't seem to apply.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure how efficient it would be with your workflow, but you could use a [Library](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/reusing-graphics-text.html) loaded with defined image frame sizes.

Comment: This is possible in InDesign CC2018, but not in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text Frame Auto Size Options and General options have nothing to see with images: they interact with Text (as their name suggests ^^)

Besides, there is no way to apply a fixed width to a frame with Object style.
So the idea is to create an object Style that fits content proportionally (stick it to top), make sure frame height is bigger than image height and then click on "Fit frame to content" icon.

That would be the manual way. If you want to automate this, a script would be needed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I could of sworn I had an Object style some time ago that could do this, but I guess I was manually setting the dimensions + autofit content.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a tweak to specify fixed width for a Text Frame... not for Image frame (as far as I know ^^). Maybe that's the one you were thinking about: https://indesignsecrets.com/make-an-object-style-specify-frame-width.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to automate the frame size of the image but not scale the image in the frame. Choose > Window > Styles > Object Style - Create "New" - go to "Size and Position Options" > Choose "Adjust - Height and Width" to your specific dimensions.

Apply to each image as needed.

This is great for creating uniform page tabs, image catalogs, or book design. What this setting doesn't do is resize or scale your image, wish it did.

A little trick to resize all of the images to uniform is to click on the image, choose "Auto Fit" first from the top task bar, then apply your Object style. Be sure to choose the little icon, "center position" before you apply the style - this will align your image squarely within the frame. Good Luck. -KG